# Emberjs, Create a search bar that filters a list

Tags: search, view, ember.js, filtering, handlebars.js

I am looking to make an input bar that searches through a list of objects.

This is an example provided by Tom and Yehuda for what I want. It works. http://jsbin.com/ulukep/87/edit.

**My problem is** that my code is not working for this example. For instance, I am trying to sort a list of `{{categoryNames}}` from the `{{recordCategories}}` model.

recordCategories.hb

```
{{#each itemController="recordCategory"}}
  <p>{{categoryName}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

**Problem #1** is trying to integrate Yehuda's handlebar helper with my list of recordCategory categoryNames. This is what they have.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('autocomplete', Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'controls/autocomplete',

  filteredList: function() {
    var list = this.get('list'),
        filter = this.get('filter');

    if (!filter) { return list; }

    return list.filter(function(item) {
      return item.name.indexOf(filter) !== -1;
    });
  }.property('list.@each', 'filter')
}));
```

I separate all views,templates, and controllers into separate files and folders, but I'm not sure where I should be placing this. In the `recordCategories/recordCategory_view.js`? Also would I replace everything that says `'list'` with `'recordCategories'`?

**Problem #2** is how I would display the `{{autocomplete list=list1}}`. I get that the handlebar is named `{{autocomplete}}` because that is how it is called as an Ember.Handlebar but how would I implement the `list=list1`? `recordCategories = categoryName`? `recordCategories=recordCategories`? I'm not sure

Comment: You'll need to be way more specific about which part of this you need help with. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have completely reworded the problem, linking a working example that I am having trouble implementing into my own project. I hope this helps.